# HTML My css styles arent being outputted even though i have linked them

Tags: html

[Image of my website page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6kT4.png)

[Image of the css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpsIM.png)
As you can see the background and font change are not showing up even though I have linked them and refreshed the page numerous times after saving.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow... please read the guidelines and ask the question again. Pay special attention to the instruction *not* to put images of code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please copy and past your code using the WYSWYG editor, or Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

try these

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css" />
```

use only main.css if the css file is in the same folder as your index.html

use ./styles/main.css if the css file is in another folder.

send a ss with your root folder with the files you are using in this project if it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you it worked, I used only main.css since they were in the same file.

Comment: no problem. I suggest you to use Visual Studio Code instead of Sublime